# Laravel background image from storage

Tags: css, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

any help would be really appreciated on this background image, from storage.
The following queries works on normal img src, but not on the background image.

```
background-image: url({{ Storage::get("{$post->image}") }});

background-image: url({{ Storage::url("{$post->image}") }});
```

Comment: A bit more code would help a lot and give more context on where the code is used. I think you made a typo copy pasting code. It should be ```background-image: url({{ Storage::get($post->image) }});
 ```

Comment: I have an observer that store the image, for a blog post.

$post->image =  request()->file('image')->storeAs(
'public/images', time().$image->getClientOriginalName());

Comment: You should have just save the image names in db and then access it in css! Using `Storage::get` in css isn't a good idea!

Answer (score 0):

When using background image and url you'd need to escape the characters using quotes inside the `url` function and remove brackets inside `get` method:

```
background-image: url('{{ Storage::url($post->image) }}');
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have tried that as well. It renders an empty string in the browser. background-image: url("");

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using.

```
background-image: url('{{ Storage::url($post->image) }}');

background-image: url('{{ Storage::url("{$post->image}") }}');
```

Both of the above works.